# Sudoku as Poetry: A Tag-Fusion Masterpiece

Tags: rhyme, poetry, sudoku

<sup>This is an entry in the 19th [fortnightly topic challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292): ***[Unconventional Tag Fusion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5614)***.</sup>

---

I wrote some poetry for you, but it's hidden within this sudoku.  Solve the puzzle and find the poem.

[image: sudoku grid]

For those who want a text version, try this:

```
C..OZE.K...T..A..I...FDSG
X..MS...BF.K.PD...GY.C.T.
......Q.V.OZU....L..MAX.I
YAEVN...IW.B....K.ZC..QR.
.GW.F.N.U.E.V.I.S...K.L..
.C..E..........QA..LXI...
...K..E.F.BN....H...C.TZM
B..Z.P.X...OIG.NW.C.E.Y..
.Y..................N..BV
.R..V.TBM.QCK.....D..W.U.
..ABQ...G........RXP.U...
.EG.H.ASO..U....BC.W.X.V.
OW.DCR..XZP..I.T.V.U..AM.
.TVI...U.Y.SAB.L..Q..NZFK
.....IBV.P..W..Y...S.TE.Q
......Y..Q..MN.....HOVC.E
.V.QR.U...S.PK.M....TH...
W...B..E..DA.Q.......P...
..OCYBM...V.E.X.R..K....L
K.Z.M.D...G.LT...PYE..RQ.
....A....O.V....TKP.FGBC.
.P..G......LCZ.VOH..QM...
..C.....QT..BU.Z..EA..V..
H.BX.....KAG.E.R.D.M..P..
.ZQYD........R..L..B...H.
```

Comment: Looks fun! I think "J" is our odd letter out for the 25x25 grid.

Comment: A non-colour version would have been nice

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## The poem is ...

> **I tried to solve a sudoku
>
> Without a clue of what to do
>
> I guessed and queried quite perplexed
>
> Eventually I got quite vexed
>
> I finally solved the tricky quiz
>
> And now know what tag fusion is**

**The completed sudoku puzzle looks like this**
- hopefully no errors made in the transcription from the original text version

> [image: Sudoku as Poetry solution]

**Original text version solution** - this is what I used to solve it:

> ```
> CulOZ EpKhr nTymA wqIvx bFDSG
> XqiMS ozlBF rKhPD aueGY vCwTn
> dbkpt sQyVc OZUwg hnLfr MAXeI
> YAEVN tgdIW fBsxl pKmZC hoQRu
> rGWhF aNmUx EqVcI bStod KyLpz
>
> uCmwE yohzn trfvp QAbkL XIsgd
> qxpKo gEiFu BNdaw sHyrv ClTZM
> BdhZl PsXkv mOIGu NWfCt EqYar
> aYtsi qrcwd zexlh upomg NkfBV
> gRfnV lTBMa QCKsy eixDz pWoUh
>
> sfABQ nltGe kmzov idRXP wUhyc
> zEGrH fASOm lUtyq kBCnW dXiVp
> OWyDC RkqXZ PfgIn TeVhU lbAMs
> pTVIx hwUdY cSABe LmgQo rNZFK
> mknlu IBVcP xdWhr YfzaS gTEoQ
>
> flxap kYgrQ uiMNb dzstH OVCwE
> eVdQR wUonl SyPKz Mcabi THgxf
> WhsgB cvEti DArQo fxuln zPmky
> tiOCY BMzps VhEfX gRqwK adunL
> KnZuM xDfah GwLTc ovPYE isRQb
>
> lmueA zhryO iVnds xTKPq FGBCw
> iPrtG uxweb yLCZk VOHsf QMnda
> nsCfk dipQT hxBUm ZgwEA yrVlo
> HoBXw vcnlK AGqEf RyDuM szPit
> vZQYD mfasg wpoRt cLniB uekHx
> ```

Uppercase are letters that were supplied; lower-case were added while solving.

It should be noted that the sudoku is not fully constrained; I was left with a handful of naked pairs & triples that couldn't be resolved without just arbitrarily picking a letter somewhere and working with it.

> OYZ at col 9 row 6&21 / row 21 col 6&9 / row 2 col 6&7 / col 7 rows 2&6
> BS at col 22 rows 13&20 / col 25 row 13&20 / row 13 col 22&25 / row 20 col 22&25

**For the colored squares ...**

> Reading each color in order as it appears in the puzzle, you get:
>
>  $\begin{array}{lcl}\mathbf{blue}&&\text{EveNtuallYigotqUITevEXed}\\ \mathbf{violet}&&\text{AndnoWKnoWwhAtTAgfuSiOnis}\\ \mathbf{yellow}&&\text{wIthOutaclUeOFWHattodo}\\ \mathbf{green}&&\text{IGuessEdANdqueRiedQuItEPERPlexED}\\ \mathbf{indigo}&&\text{iFINaLLysolvEDThETricKyQUiZ}\\ \mathbf{orange}&&\text{asUdOkU}\\ \mathbf{red}&&\text{ITriedTOsOlve}\\ \end{array}$

Adding spaces and putting the lines in their spectral ordering ROYGBIV<sup>*(thanks OP!)*</sup> gives the poem as presented above.

**How I solved it**

> I solved what I could via normal Sudoku rules.  When I got stuck, I look at the text of the messages and guessed what letter or entire word choices seemed highly likely to complete the poem, and used those to fill in their colored squares in the grid. Then back and forth between those two methods until I got the whole thing done.

Comment: Whoa, this is amazing!

Comment: Good work!  I was trying to make sure there was a unique solution, but the size of the puzzle made it difficult. I figured that the poem would provide enough clues to resolve any ambiguities, which it seems it did.

Comment: The intention was to order the lines in spectral order: **RED-ORANGE-YELLOW-GREEN-BLUE-INDIGO-VIOLET**.

Comment: Oh - yeah I see that now.  I wondered if there was a method to their ordering beyond textual context, but at that point I'd used textual context so often that one last time seemed to make sense. And since my choice of color namings differed radically from yours I didn't pick up on the spectrum aspect.  
Anyway - great fun, great puzzle, A++++++ would solve again.